# How to count distinct string cases by group and include zero in Stata?

Tags: stata

I have a dataset with the following structure:

```
clear
input year str2 state str11 document
2009 AS 09420849920
2006 AS 91444492147
2008 AS 91444492147
2007 AK 47080474742
2006 AK 90190072284
2007 AK 90190072284
2006 AK 10744281448
2009 AL 22408712220
2006 AS 92974278888
2008 AL 27189228210
2009 AS 92974278888
2009 AS 22408712220
2009 AL 92974278888
2006 AS 27189228210
2007 AS 91444492147
2006 AL 27189228210
2008 AL 47080474742
2008 AL 10744281448
2008 AK 09420849920
2008 AL 47080474742
end
```

I would like to count how many distinct documents there are in each group of year-state and include zeros. In other words, I want my output like this:

```
  +----------------------------+
  | year   state   n_documents |
  |----------------------------|
  | 2006      AK             2 |
  | 2007      AK             2 |
  | 2008      AK             1 |
  | 2009      AK             0 |
  | 2006      AL             1 |
  | 2007      AL             0 |
  | 2008      AL             3 |
  | 2009      AL             2 |
  | 2006      AS             3 |
  | 2007      AS             1 |
  | 2008      AS             1 |
  | 2009      AS             3 |
  +----------------------------+
```

I tried to solve this problem using tag function from `egen` command:

```
egen tag = tag(year state document)
egen n_documents = total(tag), by(year state)

collapse (first) n_documents, by(year state)

sort state year
list, sep(0) abb(20)
```

However, I end up with the following dataset (without zeros):

```
  +----------------------------+
  | year   state   n_documents |
  |----------------------------|
  | 2006      AK             2 |
  | 2007      AK             2 |
  | 2008      AK             1 |
  | 2006      AL             1 |
  | 2008      AL             3 |
  | 2009      AL             2 |
  | 2006      AS             3 |
  | 2007      AS             1 |
  | 2008      AS             1 |
  | 2009      AS             3 |
  +----------------------------+
```

Of course, I could just include manually the remaining combinations of year-state without documents, but in real life my dataset has almost one million observations, so a manual solution is not practical here. Is there a way to do this in stata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the data example and clear description. One trick to do this is to `reshape wide` and back to `long`, then `replace` missings with 0.

```
clear
input year str2 state str11 document
2009 AS 09420849920
2006 AS 91444492147
2008 AS 91444492147
2007 AK 47080474742
2006 AK 90190072284
2007 AK 90190072284
2006 AK 10744281448
2009 AL 22408712220
2006 AS 92974278888
2008 AL 27189228210
2009 AS 92974278888
2009 AS 22408712220
2009 AL 92974278888
2006 AS 27189228210
2007 AS 91444492147
2006 AL 27189228210
2008 AL 47080474742
2008 AL 10744281448
2008 AK 09420849920
2008 AL 47080474742
end

egen tag = tag(year state document)
collapse (sum) n_documents=tag, by(state year)

reshape wide n_documents, i(state) j(year)
reshape long
mvencode n_documents, mv(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way to do it.

```
clear
input year str2 state str11 document
2009 AS 09420849920
2006 AS 91444492147
2008 AS 91444492147
2007 AK 47080474742
2006 AK 90190072284
2007 AK 90190072284
2006 AK 10744281448
2009 AL 22408712220
2006 AS 92974278888
2008 AL 27189228210
2009 AS 92974278888
2009 AS 22408712220
2009 AL 92974278888
2006 AS 27189228210
2007 AS 91444492147
2006 AL 27189228210
2008 AL 47080474742
2008 AL 10744281448
2008 AK 09420849920
2008 AL 47080474742
end

contract year state document, zero freq(distinct)  
replace distinct = distinct > 0 
collapse (sum) distinct, by(state year)

list , sepby(state)

     +-------------------------+
     | year   state   distinct |
     |-------------------------|
  1. | 2006      AK          2 |
  2. | 2007      AK          2 |
  3. | 2008      AK          1 |
  4. | 2009      AK          0 |
     |-------------------------|
  5. | 2006      AL          1 |
  6. | 2007      AL          0 |
  7. | 2008      AL          3 |
  8. | 2009      AL          2 |
     |-------------------------|
  9. | 2006      AS          3 |
 10. | 2007      AS          1 |
 11. | 2008      AS          1 |
 12. | 2009      AS          3 |
     +-------------------------+
```

EDIT @Romalpa Akzo pointed to this more direct solution

```
 contract state year document, nomiss
 contract state year, freq(n_document) zero
```